# Custom sync through different SQL servers?

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization

I am currently working on a project, where every user has to have its own local database on his laptop in order to go offline and work on the road. Whenever he comes back to the office, he plugs in his network cable and syncs the database manually with the master database.

I am looking for an easy "1-click-solution" with already presetted sync configurations.

So for example, I'd like to sync all data in my tables except some certain ones. Though, all stored procedures need to be synced.

It needs to be executed by arguments, so I am able to make it run kinda as a script e.g. everytime the user logs in.

PS: I heard that the red gate tools are pretty good. What do you guys think of it?

Comment: I don't know about their sync tool specifically but I can tell you that the RedGate tools overall are fantastic. If there is a product that does what you need from them, I'd use it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare command lines to achieve this.

In your SQL Data Compare project file you can select specific tables and save this in a project file, and reference this from the command line. Or you could use the /include and /exclude switches.

Here is documentation to the [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content/SQL_Compare/help/10.2/sc_cl_Switches_in_the_cl) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content/SQL_Data_Compare/help/10.0/SDC_CL_Switches) switches.

You can post questions on [our forum](http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/index.php) if you need any assistance.